# Selecting every last element of a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I couldn't find a similar question so I decided to ask this one. I have a nested list with many sublists of equal length. To make things easier let's say it's like that:

```
list={{2,1,7},{3,9,5},{4,8,6}}
```

I'd like to get a list of last elements from each sublist, in this case:

> {7,5,6}

I'm not sure whether i should think of a pattern to do this or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Here are a few options: 1. `Last /@ list` 2. `list[[All, -1]]` 3. `list /. {___, i_Integer} :> i`

Comment: `list[[;; , -1]]`

Comment: `Transpose[list][[-1]]`

Comment: That was fast - thanks guys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is

```
list = {{2, 1, 7}, {3, 9, 5}, {4, 8, 6}};
list[[All, -1]]
(* {7, 5, 6} *)
```

or

```
Last /@ list
(* {7, 5, 6} *)
```

Comment: For beginners, the latter command is shorthand for Map[Last[#]&,list]

Comment: Actually `Map[Last, list]`

Comment: @Rojo Hehe... :-)