# Drop last element of parts of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

just a simple question for now I guess:

I have a list:

```
list={{1, 2, 1}, {1, 10, 1}}
```

I simply want to Drop the last element of the two entries of the list, that is the 1's at the end. I tried it this way:

```
Table[Drop[list[[x]], -1], {x, 1, Length[list]}]
```

but I don't like it this way. I feel I'm always stuck on using this Table-function,and I'm pretty sure this can be done in a much easier way

Comment: duplicate? :) [every last element from list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41201/5478)

Comment: @Kuba `Complement[Duplicate[]]` ;-) but voting to close anyway because similar questions around here have tons of good answers on that topic, esp. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/131)

Comment: @YvesKlett :) agree. Also related: [4030](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4030/5478)

Comment: I'd use `list[[All,;;-2]]`

Comment: @LeonidShifrin This is just the kind of question that will get a dozen brilliant answers even if it is *kind* of RTFM :D

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Still longer than Paxinum's ;)

Comment: @Kuba Yep. But faster :)

Comment: @YvesKlett Right, exactly of this type )

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
Most/@yourList
```

This should perhaps be the shortest way to do it.

Comment: That's great..thanks..didn't know Most until now..

Comment: learn Map(/@),and then Apply(@@) and Apply[f,expr,{1}](@@@)